# Keep only first match from locate output

Tags: scripting, locate

I need to `locate` a library on my system and it's name is expected to be found a couple of times. I want to keep only the first occurrence.

So far I've tried some methods for splitting strings by newlines but neither seem to work with `locate`'s output.

I'm not using `find` because I don't know where the lib may be in advance.

Any other (better) way to handle this is also welcome.

Comment: Please add some of the output you're getting from `locate`. You can use commands such as `grep` & `head` to filter the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to filter the output from `locate`.

#### Method #1 - be explicit

If you know you're looking for a particular version of the library, then just ask `locate` for it directly.

```
$ locate libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so
/usr/lib/libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so
```

#### Method #2 - grep

If you're looking for glibc .so libraries then use `grep` to find only these results from `locate`.

```
$ locate libstdc++ | grep ".so$"
/usr/lib/libstdc++-3-libc6.2-2-2.10.0.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libstdc++.so
```

#### Method #3 - only return the first 10 lines of the result

If you're more interested in finding the first results, then use `head` to return only the first few. You can direct `head` to return different numbers of results using the `-#` switch (shorter but non-standard equivalent of `-n #`):

#### Example

```
$ locate glibc | head -8
/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h
/usr/sbin/glibc_post_upgrade.i686
/usr/sbin/glibc_post_upgrade.x86_64
/usr/share/aclocal/glibc2.m4
/usr/share/aclocal/glibc21.m4
/usr/share/doc/glibc-2.12
/usr/share/doc/glibc-common-2.12
/usr/share/doc/glibc-2.12/BUGS
```

(note that it returns 8 lines, that's not necessarily the same as file paths as file paths can be made of several lines since the newline character is as valid as any in a file name).

Comment: Head is the command I was looking for. I needed only the first one so I used `head -1`

Answer (score 3):

Some `locate` implementations like RedHat `mlocate` or GNU `locate` (the two most common ones on Linux-based operating systems) and most BSD's have a `-l` option for that:

```
locate -l1 mylib
```

If not, you're going to have to make the assumption that file names don't contain newline characters and pipe the output of `locate` to `head -n 1` (some implementations of `locate` support a `-0` option to delimit results with NUL characters instead of newline, but those also support `-l` anyway).